# Touchscreen OS Selector

Tags: windows, android, operating-systems, tablet, touchscreen

Does anyone know if a way to create a touchscreen based "OS selector"?

I am looking at wiping my tablet, installing the latest version of windows, and then also putting Android on there. Because its a tablet, I would want to use the touchscreen in order to select an operating system.

By default, the Teclast x80 comes with such a selector. You turn the tablet on, it comes up with Windows, or, Android. You click on it to highlight it, and it counts down from 10 to 1 in the background, you then either let the timeout complete, or, you choose OK and start the boot.

I dont know if I can extract this particular boot selector from the tablet, prior to wiping the device, or, if I can rebuild a similar touchscreen solution.

Comment: Touch Screen capability would be a function of the bootloader itself

Comment: thanks for that, is there a way I can extract that from the bootloader.